# Would this kind of paraphrasing be called "plagiarism"?

Tags: thesis, plagiarism

**Original Text:**

> The questionnaire was designed by the researcher to gather data on the
> perceptions of students based on their experiences in the blended
> environment. It consisted of Likert-type items and open-ended
> questions. The content of the questionnaire was derived from a
> literature review on blended learning and authenticity of learning,
> from conversations with teaching staff, and from the researcher‟s
> previous experiences in the use of blended format in teaching and
> learning. Experts from Doctoral Committee were asked their opinions in
> order to ensure content validity.

**My Text**

**This part will be readded after finalizing my thesis.**

Comment: Give some context. Who's is the original text?

Comment: I edited the text. The original text is from the thesis that I use questionnaire from.

Comment: @Cruwiel The question makes no sense with your edit...

Comment: I know, I will finalize and my submit my thesis soon. Now I'm worried that turnitin would be like "you stole this part from this question". That's why I'll readd it after submitting my thesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that (Gedik, 2010) is the source of the original, I don't think you have a problem since, (a) you give the citation and (b) the ways to express the needed ideas here are very limited.

You are clearly making reference to the original work. And it is clear you are describing the work of another.

The essential elements describing the questionnaire must all be present and you have minimally done that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This is my first time writing a thesis and I'm concerned about the turnitin thing. I know that every institute has it's own rules for turnitin like what percentage is acceptable etc. When I use websites for comparing these two texts, I get something like "40% similarity" because it compares every single word... Is it how turnitin works? I hope that, for example this specific example would give result like "3-4% similarity"

Comment: Hopefully there is a human advisor who can discount any anomalies. And also able to give you advice. But just fighting the wording to overcome a robot is counterproductive for the expression of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As plagiarism can be defined as taking another’s language, thoughts, ideas or expressions then yes  I suggest that is plagiarism. So you should reference the source.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism

This answer was written **before** the OP edited the question showing that it would be referenced.

Comment: No no, I will definitely add references. I edited the text. I'm planing to use this in my thesis. The original text is from the thesis that I use questionnaire from. Can I add this to my thesis with referencing the source?

Comment: No. That is what the answer says you can't.